# Covering a rectangular board with Tetrominoes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, puzzle, combinatorial-geometry, tiling

I am reading about a puzzle question that is about Tetrominoes and proving that if a rectangular board can be covered with T-Tetrominoes the board's number of squares has to be a multiple of 8.
The solution first proves that if a rectangular board can be covered by Tetrominoes **one of the sides must be even**. This part is clear.
Now the solution is using a coloring "trick" i.e. it colors both the board and the Tetrominoes. The coloring of the tetrominoes is either e.g.

```
-----------------------
|-BLACK-|-WHITE-|BLACK|  
 -------|-BLACK-|-----
         -------
```

or

```
------------------------- 
|-WHITE-|-BLACK-|-WHITE-|  
 -------|-WHITE-|-------
         -------
```

Also the rectangular board is considered as colored like a chessboard.
The part that I don't understand is the following.
Based on the fact that was proven earlier i.e. that one of the rectangular boards side **must be even** if the rectangular board can be covered with Tetrominoes at all, the solution consider this ***implies that the number of black equals the number of white***.
This part (black = white) is not obvious to me. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that one side has $2n$ cells. Then every row parallel to that side has $n$ black and $n$ white cells. Thus, if there are $m$ rows, there are $mn$ black and $mn$ white cells.

Comment: The part that is not clear to me is why there will be `n black and n white`. Is it because of the mention that the board is colored as on a chessboard? Because if that was omitted it would it still be true?

Comment: @Jim: Yes, it’s because in each row (and each column) the colors alternate. Thus, either you get $n$ pairs WB or $n$ pairs BW.

Comment: The colors are alternate in a chessboard. If that sentence was omitted from the puzzle description we could not do such an inference right? Or is there something else too?

Comment: @Jim: It’s not part of the statement of the puzzle: it’s something that we do as part of the proof. That is, we **choose** to color the board like a chess board.